# Why doesn't this S3 bucket policy allow my IAM user to put objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "statement1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/userName"
        },
        "Action":  "*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-super-awesome-bucket-name-test/*"
    }
}
```

Using AWS CLI I am able to list the contents of the bucket:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-super-awesome-bucket-name-test

2017-06-28 19:50:42         97 testFile.csv
```

However, I can't upload files:

```
aws s3 cp csv_sum.js s3://my-super-awesome-bucket-name-test/

upload failed: ./csv_sum.js to s3://my-super-awesome-bucket-name-test/csv_sum.js An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Is there something else I need to do to grant my IAM user access? I added the required information via aws configure, is there something else needed?

Comment: It's possible that the `aws s3 cp` command also requires permissions on the **Bucket**, as well as the contents of the bucket. Try adding a second resource of `"arn:aws:s3:::my-super-awesome-bucket-name-test"` (without the `/*`).

Comment: So it turns out that it must have been something caused by my AWS CLI client, I installed it on my mac via homebrew. Trying the same command from my Linux PC had no issues.  Lesson learned, just stick with Linux

Comment: To install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on a Mac, simply use `sudo pip install awscli`. It works perfectly fine on a Mac!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but...

If you wish to grant Amazon S3 access to a specific IAM User, it is much better to **assign a policy directly to the IAM User** rather than adding them as a special-case on the S3 bucket policy.

You can similarly **assign permissions to IAM Groups**, and then any User who is assigned to that Group will inherit the permissions. You can even **assign permissions for multiple S3 buckets** this way, rather than having to modify several bucket policies.

Comment: That all makes sense to me, sage advice!